# git folder download utility with python?

Tags: python, git, url, download

hello is there an good utility or package that handles git folder download ?

example

```
getsomething = {
    'htmlpurifier' : 'http://repo.or.cz/w/htmlpurifier.git'
}

for key in vendors:
    # someutility.get(http://repo.or.cz/w/htmlpurifier.git,htmlpurifier)
    someutility.get(vendors[key],key) 
    # get http://repo.or.cz/w/htmlpurifier folder to /htmlpurifier  on localstorage ?
```

**if there is anything similar?**

Comment: btw please tell me why is it down voted ? i tried google with "python  download utility" or similar but i cant find one. if there isn`t any please do tell.

Comment: I have upvoted you as there was no explanation as why it was downvoted. However, whats wrong with using git commands to clone or download the git repo. You can invoke it using python "subprocess" module.

Comment: like `os.system('git clone foldername');` ? yes but its better if there is some good utility that already doing stuff like this that any of you know and i dont.

Comment: Yes, unless you want to use the tools like : http://gitorious.org/git-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to use git commands directly and wrap it using subprocess module.

How ever, if you are looking for modules to interact with Git, I can think of

- dulwich : http://www.samba.org/~jelmer/dulwich/docs/index.html
- git-python: http://gitorious.org/projects/git-python/

For git-python, particularly, please look at class : Repo. It has a function:

```
fork_bare(path, **kwargs)  
Fork a bare git repository from this repo 
path is the full path of the new repo (traditionally ends with name.git)  
options is any additional options to the git clone command 
Returns git.Repo (the newly forked repo)
```

Also you can checkout: http://packages.python.org/GitPython/0.3.2/tutorial.html#using-git-directly

```
git = repo.git
git.checkout('head', b="my_new_branch")
```

Answer (score 0):

> GitPython is a python library used to interact with git repositories

-- [GitPython docs](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro.html)

If by "git folder download" you mean clone the Git repository this should do it:

```
from git import Repo
repo_url = "http://repo.or.cz/w/htmlpurifier.git"
local_dir = "/Users/user1/gitprojects/"
Repo.clone_from(repo_url, local_dir)
```